# Adding Panels to a Form in C# during execution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I've been diving into C# for the first time by trying to recreate a screensaver that I made in Java comprised of a grid of panels which change color randomly.  So far, I've gotten the code for the panels to work, and now I'm trying to add them to a Form to prototype the layout.  I plan to determine the number of panels to be displayed at runtime (so that 16:9, 4:3, 16:10, etc. can all make the screensaver look good), but the only ways that I've found from searching the internet to add elements to a Form involve using Visual Studio's design tools.  Therefore, I have a few questions:

How can I set up the layout of the Form in something akin to Java's GridLayout?

What's the code needed to add elements to a Form?

Is there a better thing for me to be using *instead* of a Form?

Comment: I presume you're talking about Windows Forms, but if you were to tell us, then I wouldn't need to presume.

Comment: Yes, Windows Forms.  Sorry about any confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add panels to a form at runtime the same way the designer does - construct the Panel, and add it to the form (via `this.Controls.Add(thePanel);`).

The easiest way to see the appropriate code is to add a panel to the form using the designer, then open up the "YourForm.designer.cs" file.  The designer just generates the required code for you - but you can see the exact code required to duplicate what the designer would create.

As for the layout, I'd recommend watching the [Layout Techniques for Windows Forms Developers](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=324332) video.  It may give you some good clues as to the various options available for layout.  There is nothing exactly like Java's GridLayout, though there are some [open source projects that attempt to duplicate this functionality](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnetgridlayout/).

Answer (score 3):

You definitely are gong to need to create a form application to get this to work. In addition, every control you see in the designer, can be added programmatically.

You could have a method that cranks out new panels as needed....

Here is the code that will create a new panel:

```
 Panel panel1 = new Panel();
```

Once it is declared, you can access all the properties.

To add the panel to the form you would do something like this....

```
 myform.controls.add(panel1);
```

So knowing that, you can create a method that will format your panel and return or add it tor the form....

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `TableLayoutPanel` or something along those lines.  Then you can use the `Controls` property to add panels to it.